# Playground returning: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after power-cycle of host

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I was able to run the playground on `localhost` yesterday. Then I turned off the computer.

Today, I restarted `nix-shell` and started the client/server, but now the browser is not loading and giving error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Tried changing the webpack:server value in `package.json` and rebuilt the code, but still did not help.

Any idea why it was working one day and not the next day?

Comment: What OS is this? Did you restart the playground server? Is the process still alive?

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question. I just reinstalled the repositories and rebuild the code following the 1st lecture. Not seeing the problem now. Thanks.